# How can we assign owner's address in an OwnableUpgradeable contract?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, hardhat, openzeppelin, chai

So, I was testing my contract using Hardhat. So here's my doubt, somehow in my contract owner() and _msgSender() functions are returning different values (0x000.. in owner() ). Can someone pls guide me, or is it something I'm not doing right.
(I've used Openzeppelin wizard for framing the contract, so i suppose there isn't a syntactical error. I might be making some logical mistake )

```
contract MyToken is Initializable, ERC20Upgradeable, ERC20BurnableUpgradeable, 
PausableUpgradeable, OwnableUpgradeable, UUPSUpgradeable {

//This is the inheritance skeleton of my contract.
....
....

}
```

And this is the test case which fails :

```
describe("Deployment",function(){
    it("Should set the right owner",async function (){
        expect(await hardhatToken.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
    });
});
```

If anyone can help me out here, it would be really great.
-Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you called the __Ownable_init() function (this sets the owner to the current caller)? This needs to be protected with the initializer modifier, so that it can only be called during an upgrade:

```
contract MyToken is ... {

    function init() public initializer {
        __Ownable_init();
    }
}
```

This must be called during the deployment in hardhat.

Comment: Yes, I have done that, 
Here's my initialize() function: 

function initialize() initializer public {         
         __ERC20_init("MyToken", "WLT");                            
        __ERC20Burnable_init();
        __Pausable_init();
        __Ownable_init();
        __UUPSUpgradeable_init();
       
    }

Comment: And you have also called it during deployment/upgrade? Another idea: what is hardhatToken? Is it the proxy or the implementation? It needs to be the proxy

Comment: beforeEach(async function(){
        Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyToken");
        [OWNER]= await ethers.getSigners();
        hardhatToken= await Token.deploy();
    });

Here pls have a look, also could you pls clarify where exactly it needs to be called? Can't we test the contract without deploying to a testnet? I thought it uses Hardhat's network and deploys it during testing. Please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere and guide .

Comment: So you're just deploying the implementation without a proxy or calling init. Read up on the docs from OZ https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/hardhat-upgrades

Comment: It worked, thanks. I just added the deployProxy().